# Is it more efficient to filter an array or a list in Scala?

Tags: arrays, string, list, scala

Suppose I have a long `String str`, and I want to split it up, and filter out non-empty elements, and end up with a `List[String]`.

Which is more efficient of these two?

- `str.split(",").filter(_.trim.nonEmpty).toList`
- `str.split(",").toList.filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)`

In the first case, I filter the `Array`, and then turn it into a `List`. In the second, I turn it into a `List`, and then filter it.

There doesn't seem anything to be said for one over the other in terms of readability.

Comment: Why don't you do performance measurements to see? Otherwise I would choose the first approach because you first filter and then collect to List. With the second approach, I guess the toList call could end up with a list of bigger size and then you filter it. So basically you're building a list with unecessary elements within. So for me the first approach would be the best.

Comment: In terms of readability, I would also choose the first because it's clear you apply the filtering operation and then you collect the final result in the data structure you choose. But that's my opinion.

Comment: I think a better question would be how to benchmark these two code snippets.

Comment: As for performance also consider using `.view` at some point.

Comment: And also, as always, profile your actual application. It may be that the difference between these two will make no significant difference at all.

Comment: My guess is that for a reasonable size of string and heap you won't see a big performance difference. For a larger values you can use `.par`